# Why do some ImageMagick flags have plus sign (+) and others minus (-)?

Tags: imagemagick

I don't see any rhyme or reason to the use of `+` vs `-`, and I've never seen a Unix command other than ImageMagick's suite (`convert`, etc.) which expects some flags to have a `+`. Win32 commands (and ports of them to Linux) sometimes use `/`, but never `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the background behind this but personally find it quite rational. In general, the normal form is like other Linux commands preceded with a dash, or hyphen:

```
magick INPUT -something OUTPUT
```

The `+` form is used when there is a sense of:

- negation, or
- opposite direction, or
- of resetting, disabling or clearing or
- as a shorthand form.

There may be some overlap in these concepts, and maybe other additional ones exist.

---

So, in terms of *"negation"*:

```
magick INPUT -fill red -opaque blue RESULT
```

will turn all blue pixels into red, whereas this command:

```
magick INPUT -fill red +opaque blue RESULT
```

will turn all **non-blue** pixels into red.

Similarly, `-adjoin` will clump multiple images together into a single output file if possible, whereas `+adjoin` will force multiple, separate output files even when it may have been possible to make, say, a multipage TIFF or animated GIF.

Another example is `-level 10%,90%` which will **increase** contrast so that the top and bottom 10% of the brightness range are discarded and the remaining 80% are stretched across the full, permissible brightness range. On the other hand, `+level 10%,90%` will **decrease** contrast by compressing the entire possible brightness range into the central 80% of the possible brightness range.

---

In terms of *"opposite direction"*, this command will append images **vertically** below the first:

```
magick INPUT INPUT INPUT -append TALL_RESULT
```

whereas the following positive form will append images **horizontally** to the right:

```
magick INPUT INPUT INPUT +append WIDE_RESULT
```

---

In terms of *"resetting, disabling or clearing"*, this command will use Riemer dithering:

```
magick INPUT -dither RiemerSMA ... RESULT
```

whereas the following positive form will disable dithering:

```
magick INPUT +dither ... RESULT
```

If you select a couple of channels to apply a filter or threshold to, you can reset back to the default channels afterwards:

```
magick INPUT -channel alpha -threshold 50% +channel RESULT
```

If you set a fuzz for some operation, you can reset it back to zero afterwards:

```
magick INPUT -fill red -fuzz 10% -opaque blue +fuzz -opaque yellow RESULT
```

which will set the fill-colour to red, then turn all pixels within 10% of blue into that red and also all perfectly yellow pixels into that fill-colour of red.

---

In terms of *"shorthand"*, `-swap 0,2` will swap the first and third image in a sequence, whereas `+swap` will swap the last two in the sequence regardless of how many there are. This is a common operation and the plus form is succinct compared to the conventional alternative `-swap -1,-2`

Likewise, `-clone 2` will clone the third image in a sequence, whereas `+clone` will clone the last... again, a very common operation. Compare `+clone` with the more conventional-looking, but IMHO uglier alternative `-clone -1`

Likewise, `+delete` will delete the last image in a sequence.